# Evaluation Map of invertible Sheaves Isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ ringed space, $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ invertible sheaves on $X$ and $\underline{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) $ the $Hom$ - sheaf.

There is always given the canonical evaluation map $\mathcal{F} \otimes \underline{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) \to \mathcal{G}$.

My question is how to prove that this map is an isomorphism?

Comment: You don't need that $\mathcal{G}$ is invertible. It follows simply from the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because we have a canonical isomorphism $Hom_{O_X}(F, G) \cong Hom_{O_X}(F,O_X) \otimes G$ for $F,G$ invertible sheaves on $X$ if $X$ is noetherian which I am assuming. (This holds when $X$ is noetherian, $F$ is locally free and $G$ coherent).

Under this isomorphism you want to check that the map $$ F \otimes Hom_{O_X}(F,O_X) \otimes G \to G $$

is an isomorphism. This map is the composite of $\text{ev}_F \otimes id_G : F \otimes Hom_{O_X}(F,O_X) \otimes G \to O_X \otimes G$, the evaluation map tensored with $id_G$, and the multplication map $O_X \otimes G \to G$. Both maps are isomorphisms so you get an isomorphism. I hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed, it becomes clearer. But why is $F \otimes Hom_{O_X}(F,O_X) \otimes \to O_X \otimes G$ an iso?

Comment: @KarlPeter : This is because the map $F \otimes Hom_{O_X}(F,O_X) \otimes G \to O_X \otimes G$ is $ev \otimes id_G$. And the map $ev : F \otimes Hom_{O_X}(F,O_X) \to O_X, s \otimes \phi \mapsto \phi(s)$ is an isomorphism.